# Help with identifying 10pin chip

Tags: hardware

I've tried every possible combination of the markings of the chip but I can't seem to find anything on Google.

I think the chip is 96TI 35R but apart from that I can't find anything. It's like the chip doesn't exist :D

I think it's Texas Instruments.

Maybe the name is truncated but I only find the TI calculator

[image]

Comment: what device is this? can u tell?

Comment: Can you post pic of area around this chip. Did you identify any other chip near this one?

Comment: Without more circumstantial information it will be hard to help you any further. I asked around already and also tried my own luck, but everyone I asked and I myself came up empty-handed. I'd side with the other commenters: **please provide more information**.